# How to bind property of a ListBoxItem to a property already bound to ItemsSource of the ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, binding, listbox

I have a Tape object that has a property Symbols which is a List and every Symbol object has a string property Representation.

Now I have a ListBox that should display the Representations of every Symbol in Symbols in seperate TextBoxes. I already got this to work with following XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <l:TapeToTextBoxListConverter x:Key="TapeToTextBoxListConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tape.Symbols, Converter={StaticResource TapeToTextBoxListConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1, 0.5" StartPoint="0, 0.5">
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF727272" Offset="0.1"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF727272" Offset="0.9"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=parentElementName}" MinWidth="80" Height="80" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FFBFBFBF" />
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="60"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>            
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And a TapeToTextBoxListConverter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<Symbol> symbols = (List<Symbol>)value;
        List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>();
        list.Add(new TextBox());
        foreach (Symbol symbol in symbols)
        {
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Text = symbol.Representation;
            list.Add(textBox);
        }
        list.Add(new TextBox());
        return list;
    }
```

This already works and on startup I get this:
[image]

Now when the user edits the TextBoxes I want the Tape object (or to be exact the Symbols List inside it) to update.
I already tried various variations of

```
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Tape.Symbols}"/>
```

and similar stuff in the Template Setter but nothing has much of an effect. If only I'd get the convertback function in my converter triggered I'd already be happy but I can't even get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have a converter return a list of textboxes. That's unnecessary.

Get rid of the converter, use an `ObservableCollection<Symbol>` instead of `List<Symbol>` in your viewmodel, and use a `DataTemplate` to create the text boxes instead of a valueconverter. Once you're creating the textboxes properly with a DataTemplate, it's simplicity itself to bind them to the `Representation` property of the `DataContext` object -- which will be `Symbol`, since the `ItemsSource` for the `ListBox` is a collection of those.

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="listBox" 
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Tape.Symbols}"
    >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox
                Text="{Binding Representation}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Cool looking UI by the way. I like the opacity gradient effect.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need that binding, you also need it to be: Mode="TwoWay".

The way you build the list in the converter is wrong. The ListBox just needs that binding(without the converter).

Then, you define an ItemTemplate(which recieves a DataTemplate) that contains a TextBox.

On that TextBox you set the binding from your attempt with the setter(only this time on the instance itself). Only this time you will bind directly to Representation property.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding Representation, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Also you dont need that ScrollViewer over the ListBox, the ListBox already has an inner one.

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay` is the default for `TextBox.Text`. He doesn't need to tell it to use the default.

Comment: Also, you're not "defin[ing] an ItemTemplate(which recieves a DataTemplate)". There's no "ItemTemplate" type. ItemTemplate is the name of the property you're assigning the DataTemplate to